# OracleJDBC driver and Tomcat java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: oracle, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

I'm using **oracle JDBC driver** in a **dynamic web application** have this exception

```
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:106)
... 56 more
```

however the driver should be correctly loaded while deployment
[a picture showing Deployment Assembly property with oracle driver in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Fn4.png)

**Edit:** eclipse show me this warning after cleaning the project

```
Classpath entry xxxx/ojdbc6.jar will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.      service     P/service   Classpath Dependency Validator Message
```

**Edit:** information about my system:

1- tomcat 8.5: I've the driver in $CATALINA_HOME/lib btw

2- oracle 11g [ojdbc6]: with HikariCP

3- eclipse 4.14.0: +maven using jersey webapp archetype

**Edit:** it worked previously with a normal (not web) project

**Edit:** this is how i had configured the datasource

```java
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(passsword);
        config.addDataSourceProperty( "cachePrepStmts" , "true" );
        config.addDataSourceProperty( "prepStmtCacheSize" , "250" );
        config.addDataSourceProperty( "prepStmtCacheSqlLimit" , "2048" );         
        // config.addDataSourceProperty("driverClassName", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        config.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
    }
        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
//some code
```

Comment: I see you are using Hikari with a relatively old Oracle driver (ojdbc6.jar). Try a newer Oracle JDBC JAR, depending on your Oracle version. Or, alternatively, try using the Hikari `driverClassName` property. The Hikari documentation for their  `jdbcUrl` property mentions: "When using this property with "old" drivers, you may also need to set the driverClassName property". If I recall, the driver class name is simply "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver". Others may correct me, if that is wrong.

Comment: @andrewjames I've tried this solution (driver class name) previously but it didn't work, it worked in another simple (not web) project though, that's why i assumed something related to the web might be the problem

Comment: @andrewjames I've tried to use a normal driver from `DriverManager` class but the driver wasn't found either. so now i think it is a problem related to tomcat

Comment: Please show how you configure your datasource, including the properties you set. A JDBC driver included inside a WAR needs to be explicitly loaded before it can be used (automatic driver loading only works for drivers on the initial classpath).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel done. I have added the ojdbc6.jar file to WEB-INF/lib manually is there anything else i can do?

Comment: Instead of `config.addDataSourceProperty("driverClassName", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`, you need to use `config.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel unfortunately, nothing changed

Comment: I've tried to use the classic `DriverManager` but it didn't work either

Comment: If that didn't work, then it looks like the driver isn't on the classpath.

Comment: Given you are using Tomcat, as a test, can you put the driver in `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`, and also try `$CATALINA_BASE/shared/lib` if that doesn't help?

Comment: @andrewjames there is no "shared" directory in my tomcat setup I've added it to  "$CATALINA_BASE/lib" but that didn't work

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've added it to the build path property, that worked in a normal project but didn't work here unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me so far is adding `ojdbc6.jar` manually to jvm libraries `/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext` then rebooting my machine. i know this screams **BAD PRACTICE!** because others will have to that too. i won't accept this answer, and waiting for a **good** solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at [Tomcat Servlet](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/java/jdbc/Tomcat_Servlet) ?